# Required on a ngTagsInput doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I am using the [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) library in my app. Setting the required keyword is not affecting form validation. Why may this be the case?

```
<tags-input name="tags" min-length="2" add-on-paste="true" class="bootstrap" ng-model="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required></tags-input>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `required` directive probably only works on regular text inputs. Instead, you can use the `minTags` attribute of [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api):

```
<form name="myForm">
    <tags-input name="tags" min-tags="1"></tags-input>
    <p ng-show="myForm.tags.$error.minTags">Tag required</p>
</form>
```

Then you can use the `minTags` validation error key instead of `required` error key to know if the user has entered at least one tag.

Comment: Even after including `min-tags=1`, the form can be submitted. How to simulate the `required` experience?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to do that. For example you could use ng-disable to disable the submit button when the form is not valid. If you're still stuck on how to achieve this, it would be helpful to edit your question and show how you've setup your form.

Comment: I'll look into `ng-disabled` thanks. Any way to simulate the native HTML `required` experience though?